# Micronaut openapi page is blank when using jar file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, openapi, micronaut

I use micronaut with Kotlin and Gradle with Kotlin DSL.

Enabled OpenAPI which works fine when running the application from Intellij. But when starting the JAR, I get a blank page when opening for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger/views/redoc
```

Not a 404 but 200, just a blank page - no content is transferred to the browser.

Using this compiler args:

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg(
            "micronaut.openapi.views.spec",
            "-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop"
        )
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. It was a usage issue. Need to open:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger/views/redoc/index.html
```

If anyone knows how to set index.html as default, I am happy ;-)

Comment: "If anyone knows how to set index.html as default, I am happy" - If you put that information in the question that may bring more attention to it.